# Convert Scanner next string to Int and check that the text entered is a number

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char, int

I am trying to Convert Scanner next string to Int and check that the text entered is a number, if not number system print this is not a number but if number it is converted to int and divided by ten.

If i dont check for the condition in the code, the code is running as it is supposed to. But if text is entered it is calculating the charachters index value.

If the condition is there then it is making calculation for each number instead of suming up the number Before making the calculation, but it dont calculate other charachters index value.

Without checking for the condition:

```
    Scanner inputtext = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.print("Mata in ett tal: ");
    String number =    inputtext.next();  //Här matar användaren in text.              
    int sum = 0;
    double number2 = 10.0;

    for (int i=0; i < number.length(); i++) { //Här omvandlas texten till tal.

    sum *= 10;
    sum += (int) number.charAt(i)-(int)'0'; 
    }   

    System.out.println("Resultat: " + sum); //Här matas talet ut.
    System.out.println("Resultat delat med 10 : " + (sum/number2)); //Här divideras talet med 10.


  }

}
```

When checking:

```
    Scanner inputtext = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.print("Mata in ett tal: ");
    String number =    inputtext.next();  //Här matar användaren in text.              
    int sum = 0;
    double number2 = 10.0;

    for (int i=0; i < number.length(); i++) { //Här omvandlas texten till tal.
    char ch = number.charAt(i);

    if (ch == '0' || ch == '1' || ch == '2' || ch == '3' || ch == '4' ||  ch == '5' || ch == '6'|| ch == '7'|| ch == '8'|| ch == '9'){ 
    sum *= 10;
    sum += (int) number.charAt(i)-(int)'0';

    } else { 
    System.out.println("Detta är inte ett tal");
    break; 
    }
    System.out.println("Resultat: " + sum); //Här matas talet ut.
    System.out.println("Resultat delat med 10 : " + (sum/number2)); //Här divideras talet med 10.            
   }

}
```

}

I expect that if a string is entered containing numbers then the calculation is performed, if other charachters are added then the user is told that this is not a number

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What does it do that it is not supposed to do? Can you copy-paste the "wrong" output to your question and explain why you think it is wrong?

Comment: If i enter a number in the string it is supposed to be converted to its int number and then divided by ten and print out the number and print out the number divided by 10 .But if i enter something else in the string it is suppose to say this is not a number. Now if I enter 123 instead of Printing 123 and 12.3 it is Printing out 1 , 0.1 , 12, 1.2 and 123 and 12.3. It is making calculations for each loop instead , instead of Printing out 123 and 12.3.

Comment: That's because your prints are inside the for loop - you forgot to close the brace. It would have been better to use your IDE's "format" button to get proper indentation - then you would have seen this immediately. I'm going to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use methods from Character which are :

- **Character.isDigit**
- Character.isLetter
- Character.isLetterOrDigit

By using this, iterate over the string and test if all characters are number or not.

Comment: if (Character.isDigit(number.charAt(i))) { 
        sum *= 10;
        sum += (int) number.charAt(i)-(int)'0';

Comment: I get the same results by doing so

Answer (score 0):

Also, remember that "//d" stands for a digit so if you want it to scan for a digit only you can use that. I know this doesn't really explain too much but I thought a reminder might help.